# OpenGraph post failed with user Message and User Tag

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

i create an open graph action and i want to add a friend in the "message" attribute.

so i use this code `@[AaJV9NKZT5DThMKtVEAQzcwkt6i3Zo9uPdHNEABJ0-tPAv_0pdDwuvxIgah4F3lomf-w09PdtpoXgzWnkKGeCSnwMhGHqlob_kLw5Og2Pv26FA]`

The Long id with AaJV9.. comes from Facebook https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/user/taggable_friends

But every time i get this object back

```
error: Object
code: 1611150
message: "Mention tokens must be in @[username], @[userid] or @[facebook user profile URL]"
type: "Exception"
```

I hope u have an idea of fixing that. 
I use Api Vers. 2.0

here is the message example:

```
message: 'Ich packe meinen Koffer VARIABEL gemeinsam mit @[AaJV9NKZT5DThMKtVEAQzcwkt6i3Zo9uPdHNEABJ0-tPAv_0pdDwuvxIgah4F3lomf-w09PdtpoXgzWnkKGeCSnwMhGHqlob_kLw5Og2Pv26FA] '
```

Answer (score 0):

What we now know it is a bug!
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/384417055034065/